# Get content between two words - preg_match_all multiple patterns

Tags: php

I am trying to get content between two words

```
<?php
$sting= "Rabbit Cat Monkey Dog Fox Cow Rabbit Fish Monkey";


$word1 = "Rabbit";
$word2 = "Monkey";
$word3 = "Dog";
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $sting, $matches);

echo $matches[0][0];   // Rabbit Cat Monkey
echo $matches[0][1];   // Rabbit Fish Monkey
?>
```

I tried to write a code find content between word1 and[ either $word2 or $word3]; (each comes sooner) but unsuccessful:

```
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2|$word3).'/is', $sting, $matches);
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: $word2|$word3 does not work that way in PHP. You might have to loop through each word. If you don't have to use regular expressions you can just as well `explode(' ', $sting);` and loop through the resulting array yourself.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
 preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'|'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word3).'/is', $sting, $matches);
```